# MariaDB 10.3.14 DELETE statement using CTE results in Syntax Error

Tags: mariadb, common-table-expression

I am trying to use CTE in a DELETE statement (as CTEs are much more comfortable to use for me than derived tables) in MariaDB 10.3.14 but I cannot seem to get it working. 
I have spent quite a lot of time trying to solve this problem but every time I end up with "syntax error" and I don't really know why. 
When I rewrite the command to use derived table it works.

Let me show you a very simple example.
This does not work (using CTE):

```
with ps as (
    select * from product order by id asc limit 10
)
delete p from product p left join ps on p.id = ps.id where ps.id is null
```

this works without problem (derived table):

```
delete p from product p left join (
    select * from product order by id asc limit 10
) ps on p.id = ps.id where ps.id is null
```

I do not understand why the first example gives me syntax error.
The documentation is quite limited on this subject.

Please understand that this is just the most simple example to show you the problem. 
I have more complicated scenarios where using CTEs would be really helpful but I wanted to present the core of the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using 10.3.14

Comment: Is this a JPA query of some sort? `delete ---> p <--- from product p` you actually don't need this P there it should be `delete from product p ...` at least not in SQL Ansi specification

Comment: I actually do need the "p" there beacuse it's a multi-table syntax (I am using JOIN). I would not have needed the "p" if I used something like `where id in (select ....)`

Comment: Sorry you were right. My bad. Can you share the whole syntax error message please.

Comment: Sure, but it's the usual nothing-telling syntax error that MySQL/MariaDB likes to give :-/ see for yourself:


SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn:8) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'delete p from product p left join ps on p.id = ps.id where ps.id is null' at line 4
Query is : with ps as (
 select * from product order by id asc limit 10
)
delete p from product p left join ps on p.id = ps.id where ps.id is null

Comment: "nothing-telling" -- Well, nothing except for the exact place where the syntax croaked, namely between the `)` and the `DELETE`.

Comment: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18511 implies that at least Recursive CTEs cannot be used with DELETES.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you, that is what I thought but somehow did not find the link you just provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18511 implies that at least Recursive CTEs cannot be used with DELETES.